# Swift - Animating When TableView Cell Selected (didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: ios, animation, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

I've been playing around trying to animate contents of my tableviewcell when it is selected, but i'm having issues. I had read some places that you cannot run animatewithduration within didSelectRowAtIndexPath or at least it doesn't animate if you do. It seems to be the case with the code I have below, the view moves but doesn't animate.

I have tried incorporating logic into willDisplayCell to monitor for the selection but to no avail, and so I would love it if someone is able to find the right solution for me because the answer is seemingly not available, despite a lot of searching:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpandable"] as! Bool == true {
        if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false {


            // INTERESTING BIT: Animates cell contents to Right
            if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "CellHeader" {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 12, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                    cell.headerTitleLeftConstraint.priority = 999
                    cell.headerTitleRightConstraint.priority = 1
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
            }

       } else if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == true {
           // MARK: Animates cell contents back to left
           if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "CellHeader" {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 12, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                    cell.headerTitleLeftConstraint.priority = 1
                    cell.headerTitleRightConstraint.priority = 999
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                     }, completion: nil)
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you using 'let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell' in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' ?

Comment: Mr Vader, it's because I have a plist which contains all of my cell data. It is far easier that way because I have multiple collapsable levels of cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` here. It will use a cell not visible on screen and prepare to show it. What you want is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which returns a cell already on screen at the given `indexPath`.

Then I understand you want to play with 2 constraint and animate the layout changes. In order to do so, the animation should only contain `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
cell.headerTitleLeftConstraint.priority = 999
cell.headerTitleRightConstraint.priority = 1
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 12, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
```

I'd also advice you to transfer this logic from the controller to your `CustomCell` class. For example use the `selected` attribute and the `setSelected(animated: Bool)` to handle the state change visually.

Answer (score 0):

With Tanguy's help, this is how we're looking. I'm still having some animation issues because the table itself won't actually animate the next level of cells underneath, but I will improve that code and get it working. Think this is fit for purpose now, so worth posting to show the solution itself. Thanks!!

```
 override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Adjusts constraints everytime switch is tapped
        isLeftAligned = !isLeftAligned
            if userHanded == "Right" {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 12, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                self.leftHandedHeaderConstraint.priority = (self.isLeftAligned) ? 1 : 999
                self.rightHandedHeaderConstraint.priority = (self.isLeftAligned) ? 999 : 1
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        } else if userHanded == "Left" {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 12, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                self.leftHandedHeaderConstraint.priority = (self.isLeftAligned) ? 999 : 1
                self.rightHandedHeaderConstraint.priority = (self.isLeftAligned) ? 1 : 999
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: P.S. Note for others to make sure to set the tableView to MultipleSelection so that not all cells of the same type animate :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `UIView.animate(...)`. `UITableView` offers animated updating by default. After changing the constraints, you can achieve this by calling:

```swift
tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
```

Do not forget to give your height property a lower priority than `.required` when creating it. Otherwise AutoLayout will break constraints while updating (You can observe this in your debugger). Instead of setting constraints' priorities to `999` or something like that you should use static properties of `UILayoutPriority` for more readable code.

```swift
/// Set this wherever you create your height constraint, e.g. in your custom cell's class.
heightConstraint?.priority = .defaultHigh
```

The full code for `didSelectRowAt` would look like this:

```swift
    let expandedHeight: CGFloat = 500
    let defaultHeight: CGFloat = 85

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCustomTableViewCell else { return }

      /// Save the status of your cell in a property of your view model.
      if viewModel[indexPath.row].isFullsize {
        cell.heightConstraint?.constant = defaultHeight
        viewModel[indexPath.row].isFullsize = false
      } else {
        cell.heightConstraint?.constant = expandedHeight
        viewModel[indexPath.row].isFullsize = true
      }

      /// Call this for an animated update (since iOS 11)
      tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)

      /// For the same result you could also use
      /// tableView.beginUpdates()
      /// tableView.endUpdates()
      /// ...but the docs say that this will become deprecated soon

      /// Scrolls to your selected cell's top
      tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```